# html table with borders of different widths

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I get a table looking like this:

```
+=========+=========+
+ Header1 + Header2 +
+=========+=========+
+ Row1a   +  Row1b  +
+---------+---------+
```

where `==` is a thicker line (greater width) than `--`

Comment: I do not want use the `th` element as it does funny things like boldifies and centers the header text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

giver header border thickness and others thinnes

```
th
{
border: 4px solid black;
}

td
{
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PSLfj/)

Comment: I do not want use the `th` element as it does funny things like boldifies and centers the header text

Comment: If so, you should have placed your html first.

Comment: it is recommended to use the th tag for table headers, use text-align: left and font-weight:400 in your css to reset the style